# IIS 7.5 404 not found for all images via one of the http bindings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis, http-status-code-404

I have ASP.NET MVC site on IIS 7.5/Windows Server 2008 R2. Site have a set of http bindings to different domains, such as domain1.test.dev.com. domain2.test.dev.com, 10 bindings in total. They all are doing well, except one. Every request for an image(jpg, gif, png) returns 404 for this single binding. So entire layout has been loaded, all others requests feel good, but all images are broken with error 404 Not Found. There are no https bindings, they all are using http, port 80 and IP Address is 'All Unassigned'. 
Could anyone help please?

Comment: make sure your image folder and your code is the same like `~/ImagesFolder/img.jpeg`. Once again, it could be better to use base64 String.

Comment: The point is, that http://domain1.test.dev.com/images/logo.jpg returns logo, but http://domain2.test.dev.com/images/logo.jpg doesn't. It is the same site with the same folders and images.

Comment: Check folder permission.

Comment: AppPool identity has permission to read from this folder. Could different bindings have a different permissions to folder on server?

Comment: Its different, You have to check the folder itself folder=>properties. The user who are responsible to Up the application in IIS. I hope it could solve your issue.

Comment: I don't see, how permissions can be different fron one binding to another. Site is working on application pool with AppPoolIdentity. This user has permissions to read from folder with images. I suppose that it should work for all bindings. But it is not or I missed something else. The question is open =(

Comment: Is Directory Browsing enabled? I don't have your file that's why i couldn't replicate your issue.

Comment: Yep, directory browsing is enabled.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help. Can you check using Fiddler? You may get some insight on what is happening during the request response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found. There was an additional web.config file in ~/Images directory. This config contained specific redirection rule for one of the domain, so for this domain I saw 404, and others worked great. An additional web.config appeared in ~/Images directory accidentally, because of missclicking 
in URL Rewrite module on the IIS. Some time ago we have used such redirections for demo and removed them after that. The redirection rule in web.config was a kind of:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ProductionRedirectDomain1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*domain1.test.dev.com*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}domain1.com{C:2}" />
        </rule>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The bug has disappeared after removing a redundant config. Thanks, everybody!